# condition for timeoutInMinutes in azure-pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

I want to know if there is support for different values of `timeoutInMinutes` for a job based on conditions e.g. if `build.Reason` is `Scheduled` or `InvidualCI`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> condition for timeoutInMinutes in azure-pipelines

I am afraid the answer is no.

As the document [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), we could to know the condition used for `steps`, `jobs`, and `stages` by default. We could not use it for one specify property `timeoutInMinutes`.

As workaround, we could add a copy job with different values of `timeoutInMinutes` and add condition for those two jobs in the pipeline:

```
jobs:
- job: A
  timeoutInMinutes: number1
  condition: and(always(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))

- job: Copy A
  timeoutInMinutes: number2
  condition: and(always(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'InvidualCI'))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That is sad, as I have to now duplicate all my build/test instructions into two jobs